# SQL table design for two variant dimensions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to record the points the users get by participating in various events in different years, like:

```
UserName  Year   Event1 Event2 Event13 Event14 ...
 A        2001    20       30    NULL   NULL
 A        2002    15       20    30     NULL
 B        1999    7        NULL  NULL   10
 B        2000    15       10    NULL   100   
.....
```

The number of user is not fixed, and the number of Events is not fixed either.

What tables should I create to achieve this result?

I use Microsoft SQL2008 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `User` table, an `Event` table, and a `UserEvent` table.

Table `UserEvent` would have columns `UserID` and `EventID` to record a user participating in a specific event.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem this could solve it:

```
UsersTable
id | ...

EventTable
id | year | ...

UserEventMappingTable
id | user_id | event_id | points
```

Then you can use JOINS to get all information you want.

Answer (score 0):

If we apply the general concept of normalization, the scenario can be approached easily.

First we define a **EventType** and **UserType** table to define the nullable and non-nullable types.

Then we create usual **Event** and **User** Tables with eventType_id(referring to EventType table) and userType_id(referring to UserType table) defined on it.

Finally we create **UserEvent** table having event_id(referring to **Event** table), user_id(referring to **User** Table) and *Year* column.

Hope it will solve the problem. If there is any other consideration, let me know.